# Directional HDMI cable semi-working?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have a problem with directional HDMI cable. I have my laptop connected to TV through said cable. And OS detects it (checked with `xrandr --query`). When two monitors display the same thing, it works. But when I switch to external one only or "connected displays" or whatever it is called in English (the one with two desktops, one for each display), the external one turns black. Is is the cable problem or some missing drivers?

Comment: switching main display does nothing.

Comment: I think this is something with drivers. I've connected laptop to another monitor with the same cable and all options work.

Comment: Try turning the monitor off, unplug the power cable of the monitor, wait for a minute, plug the power cable back and turn the monitor back on. This may let Ubuntu re-detect the monitor properly.